# I have a GridView with several fileds. I want to be able to get row from a start-date to end-date. getting Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView with Fields i want to be able to get the rows between a start-date and a End-date. So i created a new SqlDataSource and bind it with the new SelectCommand as shown below. I don't get an error but the grid disappears. What is wrong with my code or what is the best way to do this ?

```
   .aspx

    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcalendarstart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtcalendarstop" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>  
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AttendanceDBConnectionString %>"     
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]">
```

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    PageSize="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Height="139px">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Edit" NavigateUrl="FormReport2.aspx" 
            Text="Edit" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%-- <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Editemployee" 
                CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                Text="EditRow"  />--%>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  NavigateUrl='<%#  "FormReport2.aspx?id=" & CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldEmployeeID"), String) & "&Adate=" & CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldAbsentDate"), String)& "&Acode=" & CType(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldAbsentCode"), String)& "&RuleViolationW=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldRuleViolationWarningType")& "&RuleViolationDate=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldRuleViolationIssueDate") & "&LOAEndDate=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fldLOAENdDate") %>'  Text="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldEmployeeID" HeaderText="EmployeeID" 
            SortExpression="fldEmployeeID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentDate" HeaderText="AbsentDate" 
            SortExpression="fldAbsentDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldAbsentCode" HeaderText="AbsentCode" 
            SortExpression="fldAbsentCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationWarningType" 
            HeaderText="Rule Violation Warning Type" 
            SortExpression="fldRuleViolationWarningType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" 
            HeaderText="Rule Violation Issue Date" 
            SortExpression="fldRuleViolationIssueDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fldLOAEndDate" HeaderText="LOA End Date" 
            SortExpression="fldLOAEndDate" />                                                                                                                         
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.VB

```
        Dim newdatasource = New SqlDataSource
        newdatasource.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SVR-SQLDB2;Initial Catalog=AttendanceDB;Integrated Security=True"
        newdatasource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN " & "2/12/2013" & " and " & "11/12/2013" & ","
        GridView1.DataSourceID = newdatasource.ID
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Where clause before the Order By clause.

Comment: ^ What he said, move your `WHERE` before the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Its still not working. this is how my new SelectCommand looks :"SELECT * FROM tblAbsences WHERE fldAbsentDate BETWEEN " & "2/12/2013" & " AND " & "11/12/2013 ORDER BY fldEmployeeID,fldAbsentDate,fldAbsentCode;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the Order By after the Where clause.

```
newdatasource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN " & "2/12/2013" & " and " & "11/12/2013" & " ORDER BY [fldEmployeeID], [fldAbsentDate], [fldAbsentCode]
```

Comment: I copied the line of code that you posted but its not working. any other ideas ? the behind code is fire when i click a button. And as you can see on the code it is already  databinded to another datasource when the webform first launch. Any other ideas ? appreciate the help

Comment: Maybe - `GridView1.DataSource = newdatasource`

Comment: It gives you an error: Value of type 'System.UI.WebControls.SQLDataSource' cannot be converted to 'String'

Comment: I copied your code into my code but the same keeps happening no error but the gridview does not show

Comment: Check the code behind part, just re-initialize it with the new command. Worst case you may have to set the `Datasource` to Nothing before reapplying it.

Comment: I have the fallowing error : Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. And its because you cannot have Datasource on front end and server code. I was thinking Binding all the data manually. For example on the first time the webpage fires fille the gridview with all the rows. and then when you click the button bind it to the other sqldatasource but I dont know how to bind it. It happens the same the grid does not shows when im trying to bind it with the data base and I erased the DataSourceID from aspx as I am using Datasource on server code.

Comment: You can try - not connecting the GridView to the SqlDataSource in HTML, but rather do it in code alone

Comment: But I still  cannot figure out the between sql comand: "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-21-2014T12:00:00 AM' AND '8-15-2014T12:00:00 AM'" I tried this because i saw it in another post but I get the error : "SELECT * FROM [tblAbsences] WHERE [fldAbsentDate] BETWEEN '7-21-2014T12:00:00 AM' AND '8-15-2014T12:00:00 AM'" .

Comment: Use the `<WhereParameters>` element to define the two date times. You could also do this in code as well.

Comment: [Example](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.sql-datasource/sqldatasource.filterexpression-can-t-g/570865)